# error in row or column number python openpyxl

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, openpyxl

Error trace :'python openpyxl row or column value must be at at least 1'

I'm attempting to use Python to extract data and write it to an Excel spreadsheet.

it gives me an error that row and column values must be at least 1. Though they are not by initialize value equal to 0, I add them by 1 and the error persists.

code is below;

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from datetime import datetime
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "New Title Championship"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument('start-maximized')
webdriver_service = Service(r"C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.nba.com/schedule?pd=false&region=1")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
    print('accepted cookies')
except Exception as e:
    print('no cookie button!')

element_to_save=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div/div/div/div/h4")

f=open('new_result_file00.txt','w')
f.write(element_to_save.text)
f.write("\n")
f.write(str(datetime.today()))
myList=[]
myList.append(1)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
elements_to_save=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@data-id='nba:schedule:main:team:link']")))

i=1

for element in elements_to_save:

    try:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
        f.write(" ")
        f.write(element.text)
        myList.append(element.text)
    except Exception as e:
        time.sleep(5)
        print("err",i)
        i=i+1
    f.write(" \n ")
    f.write(str(datetime.today()))

f.close()

time.sleep(1)
driver.get("https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/traditional")

season_click=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//option[@value='2021-22']")))
season_click[0].click()

d=1
teamStats = []
for d in range(len(myList)):
    xpath_template="//tr[contains(.,'{0}')]"
    xpath=xpath_template.format(myList[d])
    try:
        tr=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,xpath)
    except Exception as e:
        teamStats.append(myList[d])
        teamStats.append("new-comer-team")

    print("-",teamStats)
    for i in range(7):
        a=i+1
        teamStats.append(tr.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//td["+str(a)+"]").text)
        ws.cell(row=int(d), column=int(a), value=tr.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//td[" + str(a) + "]").text)
        print("--", teamStats)

print("---",teamStats)
driver.quit()
wb.save('first_try_nba.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you've got this error here:

```
...
for d in range(len(myList)):
    ...
    for i in range(7):
        a=i+1
        ...
        ws.cell(row=d, column=a, value=...)
```

When `d` equals zero I expect to see an error at `ws.cell(row=d, ...)` because rows and columns in Excel are numbered starting from 1. Sort of `ws.cell(row=d+1, ...)` should help.

Comment: but, i have line where d equals 1 right before loop d=1
teamStats = []
for d in range(len(myList)):

Comment: @xlmaster the initial value of `d` initially set to `1` before the loop is overwritten by `for d in range(len(myList)):` that starts with `0`. It is equal to write `d=1` and on the next line to put `d=0`

Comment: does it mean loop in python initialize like list index starting from 0? If I will assign 2 to d, then again it will start from 0?

Comment: @xlmaster `for d in range(n)` in python is sort of equivalent to `FOR d=0 TO n STEP 1` in VBA. To start from 1 we can use `for d in range(1, n+1)`. In this case, the variable `d` will sequentially take the values 1, 2, 3, ... n.